# Error installing socket.io

Tags: node.js, windows-8, installation, socket.io

I'm trying to install socket.io package in windows(8) after having successfully installed `node` and `nmp`

But installing `socket.io` the same way (`npm install socket.io`) I'm getting the following error. http://pastebin.com/EykjZ85X

`Generating code

      Finished generating code

      validation.vcxproj -> c:\~\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\Release\validation.node

    socket.io@0.9.16 node_modules\socket.io

    ├── base64id@0.1.0

    ├── policyfile@0.0.4

    ├── redis@0.7.3

    └── socket.io-client@0.9.16 (xmlhttprequest@1.4.2, uglify-js@1.2.5, active-x-obfuscator@0.0.1, ws@0.4.31)`

I'm not sure if it's an error, but running the basic test app
http://socket.io/#how-to-use 
doesn't work. It says it couldn't find the package socket.io

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like an error to me, but it's installing your module to a funky location, so I can only assume you didn't init your package.

So you create a directory for the example, initialise it with a package.json (run `npm init` in the dir) and then `npm i socket.io --save` This will create a node_modules directory inside your example directory, install socket.io to it, and will then add socket.io to the package.json (that's the `--save` part, or `-S` for short).

You should then be able to run the example.

## A bit more explanation

Node packages need a package.json file in your package's directory. So if you had a directory called `~/example`, you would need to create a `package.json` file in this directory `~/example/package.json` before you can install modules into your package. The `package.json` file keeps track of all of your dependencies, like when you install socket.io for example. To create one `cd ~/example` and `npm init` - follow instructions. You can [take a look at the docs for npm init](https://npmjs.org/doc/init.html) and what [package.json should look like](https://npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html).

When you write node code, you install packages locally inside your package (or project if you prefer to call it that) directory. npm will place the files for the module you installed inside the `node_modules` directory, so in our example we expect to see `~/example/node_modules`, and after installing socket.io we expect to see `~/example/node_modules/socket.io`. You can install some packages globally using the `-g` flag with npm, but only do that for global utilities or if you understand why you need to do this.

Comment: Can you explain or provide a link to explain in detail what this "initializing the package.json" in the "example directory" means?

Comment: Do I need to install socket.io in the directory in which I plan on creating a project in? So if I plan on creating two separate projects I need to install it 2 times?

Comment: >"funky location"< I think I messed up, I installed it in my Download directory. Do I need to install node and npm too again?

Comment: node and npm should be installed properly, you just need to install the module in the right places. You need to install it in every node package that you write that requires socket.io